# what does the test folder does in spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, annotations

i have just created the spring boot project and there is a folder named test inside the src. what does it do?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GprocApplicationTests {

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
}

}
```

while creating the spring boot project, there exists the test folder inside the src folder of the project. Inside the test folder there is a class annotated with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest. what does it do?

Comment: It loads the spring context and check if all dependencies and configurations are done in a right way. If not the test fails. You can read more [here - boot-features-testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic test that is added by the project generator.

It's primary purpose is to set up the test infrastructure for you (directories, libraries needed, etc).

This specific test makes sure that the application starts without error (because your app doesn't do anything else yet). The intent is for you to leverage this setup to add your own tests as you add functionality in the main folder.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot follows [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) approach, therefore it uses general Java project structure, that is common across build systems [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) & [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_test_type_source_files).

So, test folder contains test source files under `src/test/java`, and test resources - under `src/test/resources`. Also as a good practice Spring Boot includes test class, that validates that your application context starts properly.